# Dealing with a development VM with no internet connection

Tags: software-industry, management, developer, security

I recently just started working at a company that is going to change the way their employees develop code. They are switching from one machine (VM) that does everything, meaning communicate to other employees and develop on. To a new setup where the development machine is completely disconnected from the internet, while we have a second machine that is able to go online for communication. Since I just started working here, I'm the guinea pig in this switch. The problems arise when I try to update/download packages from Visual Studio to get up and running.

***How do I deal with needing packages from NuGet*** when I can't update/install new ones due to no internet connection?

We have a Desktop Support department where you can request new programs to be added to the VM, but I think sending a request to them every time something ends to be added or updated seems like a big waste of resources and time.

With *some* packages, I can get away with downloading them on my internet enabled VM and transfer them over to the development VM via copy/paste, but I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to go about it.

What would you recommend that I do to deal with this situation?

Comment: I'd honestly quit and find a different job. That is probably the dumbest thing I've heard a company do.

Comment: The company works with banks and credit unions, so I guess it has to deal with protecting their data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.  Might be better on StackOverflow if you can deal with sarcasm

Comment: The workplace side of this is honestly just something about which you need to talk to your manager (or whomever else is your contact person regarding this) - we can't tell you how you should handle this. If you're asking about technical solutions, you're on the wrong site (although it sounds like you already covered most of the technical solutions).

Comment: Unfortunately this is a turn-of-the-millennium mindset, when you could actually develop in a walled-off environment. Now you pretty much can't live without package managers and GitHub. You'll need to try to convince management that this runs counter to modern development, and/or a decrease in productivity because of the overhead of disconnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the point of the test phase.

The objective is to test out the system, and sometimes the conclusion is "No, this does not work."  Your experience is **extremely valuable**.  It is **imperative** that you do not circumvent your problems!

Provide your managers the feedback that, whenever you need to retrieve important updates, this new process adds a lot of time, and may even require special IT request to complete.  Document how much time you're wasting, how much it delays the development time, and let them evaluate whether it is worth the extra "security".

Answer (score 0):

The restriction is an artificial company policy. If you are the guinea pig, then it is for a reason: they want to find out if it works.

Document all problems you have, document possible fixes (own NuGet server for instance). Take this list to whoever made you the tester of this setup and go through all the issues one by one until all are fixed.

If they cannot be fixed, I guess the guinea pig is dead -figuratively speaking- and you should get back your internet access.